# How to create test PayPal Buy Buttons

Tags: php, button, paypal

I'm finding PayPal to be very fragmented for developers since the recent updates and re-designs they've done.

I can't seem to work out how to create PayPal Test Buttons. I've made real ones, but that's it.

I get thrown into the classic PayPal site after logging in to my Sandbox Business account, but most of the links bring me back to the regular PayPal where my actual account is logged in. So I can't get to the test button page.

I am either missing something big or PayPal have a few issues to sort out.

Edit:

I've tried logging into the PayPal Sandbox, and following the documentation listed on developer.paypal.com -> documentation -> payment buttons -> test payment buttons.

Under test procedures, I get stuck at 4.2: "In the Related Items box on the right, click the Create new button link.".

This option does not exist.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the steps which I usually perform to create sandbox buttons.

1. Login to [PayPal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/)
2. Navigate to [accounts section](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)
3. Create a [business account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/create)
4. Login to [sandbox account](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/home) using that account details
5. Create button as like you did in real account. `Profile -> My Selling Tools -> PayPal buttons`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get stuck at "My Selling Tools". It's as if my account (xxxxxxxxxxx-facilitator@outlook.com) isn't a business account. I have options to "Upgrade". However in PayPal Developers the account I'm logging into the sandbox with is of business type. :(

Comment: Try to access: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_button-management

Comment: It worked! But I'm still curious as to why PayPal hasn't fixed this... Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is working for me without any issues. 
Anyhow glad to know that it helped.